# How to make a custom ngIf directive without scope isolation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

I want to use ngIf directive and to make my custom `myOwnIf` directive without scope isolation. As you can see in the code here - it doesn't work for me without scope isolation.

Can someone assist in understanding the problem and the solution?

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

var MyOwnIf = (function () {
    /* @ngInject */
    function MyOwnIf($element) {
        this.isDisplay = $element.attr('my-own-if') === 'true';
    }
    return MyOwnIf;
}());

app.directive('myOwnIf', function () { return ({
    template: "<div ng-if=\"$ctrl.isDisplay\"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>",
    transclude: true,
    controller: MyOwnIf,
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    //scope: {}, --> If I will uncomment this it will work, but I don't want to isolate the scope
    bindToController: true,
    restrict: 'A'
}); });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <div my-own-if="false">This text should NOT show because value is FALSE</div>
    <div my-own-if="true">This text should show because I value is TRUE</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by scope isolation, `ng-if` doesn't isolate scope, it does create a new scope which is prototypically inherited from current scope, internal use of `ng-if` will again create a prototypically inherited scope(why don't understand the purpose of creating new directive)

Comment: @Alon, I wonder why you want this. If you're having problems updating scope values inside an `ng-if` then the solution is to use the controllerAs syntax, or even just ensure that all the model values are enclosed inside some other object. So instead of `ng-model="foo"` which won't work correctly inside an `ng-if` you have `ng-model="vm.foo"` and everything works just fine.

Comment: @Duncan, maybe I didn't understand something in angular. what I want to achieve eventually is a directive called is-mobile="boolean" that will make the content of it appear or disappear below a breakpoint of 760px. I thought isolating the scope can cause troubles, but I might have understand it all wrong and isolating the scope in that case by using transclude will not cause any harm

Comment: @Alon usually you would just do that with css (so with bootstrap css `class="hidden-xs"` does what you want though the elements would remain in the DOM. If you do want to manipulate the DOM surely `ng-if="!screen.isMobile"` and update some properties on a screen object achieves your aim.